# How to summarize the data in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please have a look on following query.

```
SELECT 
AcctName = case 
                when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) in ('6017' , '6018') then 'Equipments' 
                when substring(T1.[Segment_0],1,4) in ('6020') then 'Consultants'           
                else T1.[AcctName]
               end ,           
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS Budget, SUM(T0.[DebRLTotal]/85) AS 'Current Expenses',
    SUM(T3.[Debit]/85) AS 'Cummulative Expanses',( SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85)-   SUM(T3.[Debit]/85)) as 'UNEXPENDED BALANCE',T2.[Name]
     ,T4.[Name]  ,T3.[RefDate]   
FROM OBGT T0 
INNER JOIN OACT T1 
    ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 
    ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 
    ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account]
INNER JOIN OASC T4 
    ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code] 
    WHERE T3.[RefDate] BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31' AND T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015' and T4.[Name] = 'Faces'

GROUP BY

    case 
        when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) in ('6017' , '6018') then 'Equipments' 
        when substring(T1.[Segment_0],1,4) in ('6020') then 'Consultants'        
        else T1.[AcctName]
    end  ,T2.[Name],T4.[Name] ,T3.[RefDate]
```

the result which i am getting is like the following table:

```
| AcctName      | Budget    | currentExpenses   | date          |
|-------------  |---------- |-----------------  |-----------    |
| equipment     | 12123     | 32342             | 1may2015      |
| equipment     | 34265234  | 27364723          | 31may2015     |
| consulants    | 54635     | 474345            | 2may2015      |
| consultants   | 643654    | 73264             | 29may2015     |
```

The result which i want is like following :

```
| AcctName      | Budget    | currentExpenses   | date      |
|------------   |---------- |-----------------  |---------  |
| equipment     | 12123     | 32342             | may2015   |
| consultant    | 34265234  | 27364723          | may2015   |
```

means i want one value for whole month rather than giving me different dates. please help me out.

Comment: Use a derived table where you extract the "may2015" part from the date, and also have the current case. Then do GROUP BY as before.

Comment: i want here in this query .can we do that?

Comment: @Kirat You are doing group by  T3.[RefDate] since dates are different then you are getting multiple values respective of T3.[RefDate],Just curious how many T3.[RefDate] are in your table for specified period ?

Comment: @Kirat Try doing group By months instead of dates.

Comment: Suraj dates are depending upon the entries . i am getting here the summary according to the account code that i put in substring function. so dates can be any within may month. but i want it should show only one value for may. rather than give me different date values

Comment: `select acctname, SUM(... , newdate from (select case ... as acctname, ... cast(datename(month... as newdate from table where... ) group by acctname, ... newdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get what you want (grouping by month and year of the RefDate):

```
SELECT 
AcctName = case 
            when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) in ('6017' , '6018') then 'Equipments' 
            when substring(T1.[Segment_0],1,4) in ('6020') then 'Consultants'           
            else T1.[AcctName]
           end ,           
SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS Budget, SUM(T0.[DebRLTotal]/85) AS 'Current Expenses',
SUM(T3.[Debit]/85) AS 'Cummulative Expanses',( SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85)-   SUM(T3.[Debit]/85)) as 'UNEXPENDED BALANCE',T2.[Name]
 ,T4.[Name]  ,datename(month, T3.[RefDate]) + cast(year(T3.[RefDate]) as varchar) As MonthAndYear
FROM OBGT T0 
INNER JOIN OACT T1 
ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 
ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 
ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account]
INNER JOIN OASC T4 
ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code] 
WHERE T3.[RefDate] BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31' AND T2.[Name] =     'Main Budget 2015' and T4.[Name] = 'Faces'

GROUP BY

case 
    when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) in ('6017' , '6018') then 'Equipments' 
    when substring(T1.[Segment_0],1,4) in ('6020') then 'Consultants'        
    else T1.[AcctName]
end  ,T2.[Name],T4.[Name] ,DATENAME(MONTH, (T3.[RefDate])), YEAR(T3.[REfDate])
```

Comment: thank you very much . you have solved my problem. i was struggling from so long.. thanks.. :)